# Grub no such device error while USB storage device plugged in

Tags: 12.04, grub2, usb-drive

I have installed my Ubuntu 12.04 from USB. I have prepared my USB with Unetbootin. When I try to boot my PC while any USB storage device plugged in I am getting this error:

```
error: no such device: ac6e5541-...
```

If I remove USB storage devices on boot PC boots normally.

I am using a HP DV9087EA laptop which has two hard drives. One of them like a external drive. Windos does not sport to instal that drive but Ubuntu does not complain to install on that drive. So I have a dual boot install: Windows on first drive and Ubuntu on secon drive. Grub is installed on first drive.

Here is the result of the bootinfoscript:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5622335/

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your boot order in the BIOS settings to boot your internal hard drive before any removable (USB) devices.

Comment: I have my hard drive as first boot device.

Comment: Please run the [bootinfoscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/), [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) the results and comment back with a link. (Boot normally and then plug in the offending USBs before running the script)

Comment: I am not able to get the os selection screen when I plug in a USB. How will this script will help me?

Comment: @OlcayErtaş I said to boot first, and after plug in the USB. Running the bootinfoscript gives a good picture of what's installed and where. TBH I don't know it will help, but it's a diagnostic tool which often aids problem resolution.